# VPN , clients connect but no network

Tags: vpn, windows-server-essentials

I have a Server Essentials 2012 server that has anywhere access enabled for VPN access, and web access. this has worked fine for a year with no problems that the occasional tickle would't fix. About 1 week ago I added a 2012 r2 standard to the domain as a hyper-v host. with the intention of transitioning services to VM on this host and retiring the essentials server. that went fine, no problems. I added a vm on this host and installed the RDS role to work on transferring an access database we serve to offsite employee's. This didn't work as planned due to licensing issues, but no other problems i could find. This morning I get an email from a remote employee saying they could not connect to the vpn with error 812. the connection was prevented by a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. After a "repair anywhere access" from the dashboard, he could connect, but cant connect to any host on the lan. He cant ping any server by IP, FQDN, Computer Name, nothing. I have now established that no client can "see" the network or ping any host, even though they are connected to the VPN. I don't know if Adding a Terminal server to the domain hosed the VPN, or what. I checked DNS and everthing looks as expected. I have made no changes to the Essentials server. This is a major problem and I need Help!

Comment: Can you give routes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue... What I had to do was tell the connection to not use the remote gateway to connect through internet. On the XP machine (works on Vista and 7 also) go to the properties of the VPN connection. Click on the Networking tab and double click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4). Click Advanced and uncheck the box for "Use default gateway on remote network." This will route all of your local traffic through whatever network you're locally connected to, and any remote traffic through the VPN connection. This also assumes that you're not trying to route your internet traffic through the VPN. Also I would like to suggest you to try some other VPN services providers. Currently I am collecting all information about VPN from https://anonymweb.co.uk/. Here you can read different types of articles. I will be back after completing this.